# How can I avoid dynamically generated classes derived from metaclass not to end up as the same class?

Tags: python, unit-testing, metaclass

What I'm trying to do is to perform hundred of unit tests to a function, which I can derive from a dictionary. Unfortunately I cannot use any of the existing packages for parametrized tests (like nose), so I'm trying to get my own solution.

My intention with the following example code is to create 3 classes (one for each test) that will exist in the global scope so that unittests can pick it up and run the corresponding tests.

```
tests = [
    {'text': 'text1fdskla3fsda4',
     'result': [1, 3, 4],
     },
    {'text': 'fdsg45tg5b',
     'result': [4, 5, 5,5 ],
     },
    {'text': 'fsddf4',
     'result': [4, 2],
   }
]

def evaluate(text):
    out = []
    for char in text:
        if char.isdigit():
            out.append(int(char))
    return out

class TestMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        name = str(test['text'])
        return type.__new__(cls, name, (unittest.TestCase,), attrs)

for test in tests:
    class T(object):
        __metaclass__ = TestMeta
        def testOne(self):
            self.assertEqual(test['result'], evaluate(test['text']))
    globals()[(test['text'])] = copy.deepcopy(T)

unittest.main()
```

When I run the above code, I get four unittests, which is one more than expected, but on top of that, instead of having the output of each unittest, it seems like the class I'm creating is always the same (even if I'm actually setting a different name and parameters to each):

```
======================================================================
FAIL: testOne (__main__.fsddf4)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ble.py", line 45, in testOne
    self.assertEqual(test['result'], evaluate(test['text']))
AssertionError: [4, 2] != [4]

======================================================================
FAIL: testOne (__main__.fdsg45tg5b)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ble.py", line 45, in testOne
    self.assertEqual(test['result'], evaluate(test['text']))
AssertionError: [4, 2] != [4]

======================================================================
FAIL: testOne (__main__.fsddf4)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ble.py", line 45, in testOne
    self.assertEqual(test['result'], evaluate(test['text']))
AssertionError: [4, 2] != [4]

======================================================================
FAIL: testOne (__main__.text1fdskla3fsda4)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ble.py", line 45, in testOne
    self.assertEqual(test['result'], evaluate(test['text']))
AssertionError: [4, 2] != [4]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.002s

FAILED (failures=4)
```

deepcopy is an attempt to get a different output, but didn't help. The explicit creation of the class in the globals dict was due to the fact that simply creating the classes on the for loop just yields one unittest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond the deep attempt at meta-everything, you're running into a typical Python beginner problem: global name lookups are done at runtime.

So, in your code:

```
for test in tests:
    class T(object):
        __metaclass__ = TestMeta
        def testOne(self):
            self.assertEqual(test['result'], evaluate(test['text']))
```

when `testOne` runs, it looks up `test` in the `globals` dictionary **at that time** -- the time it **runs** -- by which time `test` is set to the value it was set to most recently, of course.

You need to force the binding to happen earlier, which you can do e.g simply by changing

```
        def testOne(self):
```

into

```
        def testOne(self, test=test):
```

This change forces the global `test` to be looked up at the time `def` executes (as opposed to the later time when the **body** of the method executes), which is the same time the `class` statement executes -- i.e, once per leg of the loop, when global variable `test` is set to the current item of list `tests`.

Comment: This makes absolute sense, pointed out seems so obvious, thanks a lot.

Comment: I wonder if as a followup you could tell me if there is a better way to get all classes created without using the line "globals()[(test['text'])] = T". Without it, for each loop cycle a new class get's created but it's overwritten in the next iteration, since every instance get's created with the label 'T' in the globals.

Comment: @user4709759, but you're **not** doing that in your sample code -- you're using a `test['text']` global name that **does** vary each time through the loop!  Anyway, `unittest.TestCase.__subclasses__` should *also* work (but you **also** need to keep somewhere a reference to each class object lest it get garbage collected, and `globals` is OK for that).

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear enough. My question was if I can somehow avoid manually copying the created class into globals with a custom label. The reason I ask this is due the the fact that this doesn't seem very clean, for example, after I run this code, I have a remaining class with a label 'T' in the globals for the last iteration of the loop, which is a repeat instance of the last class created. That's the reason I have 4 tests in the end instead of 3. So to clean this up I need to add an additional line "globals().pop('T')". But maybe this is just fine.

Comment: @user4709759, `unittest.main` **will** look in the module's `globals` for `TestCase` subclasses -- I though you wanted to rely on that discovery mechanism!  If that's not the case then you need to explicitly build a `unittest.TestSuite` (just give its ctor your list of `TestCase` subclasses), call `.run` on it with a `result` argument, do your own reporting on the end value of that result -- or many other approaches yet, far too many to squeeze in comments, so, you may want to open a separate Q!